# How to tab to next selection in Word document from Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a Word document that is set up as a grid of textboxes and an Excel document that contains a row of addresses.

My goal is to put each of these addresses in a textbox, so that I can print them off to align with mailing stickers.

If I manually copy/paste the addresses, I need to tab once to select the next textbox. However, I cannot find a way to send the "tab" command via VBA.

Is there a way to tab to select the next textbox or shape?

```
   For row = 2 To last_row
        addr = Cells(row, col)
        wordselection.TypeText (addr) & vbTab ' Tried sending a vbtab, but that doesn't affect selection
        wordselection.moveright Unit:=wdCell 'This gives an error, presumably because I'm not in a table.

        Set shp = wordapp.activedocument.Shapes("Item " & row) ' Tried getting the shape by name, but this gives an error
        shp.Select (True)
         
    Next
```

It's possible that there's an easier way to accomplish my goal other than sending a tab; I'm open to XY problems here.

Comment: Propably using content controls instead of textboxes would be a better solution for your requirement. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69905231/16578424) was a different question - but it might help you to get an idea of how that could work.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Avery mailer document was set up to use textboxes, so changing to content controls would have required a fair amount of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there's a [sendkeys statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement).

```
 For row = 2 To last_row
    addr = Cells(row, col)
    wordselection.TypeText (addr)
    sendkeys "{TAB}" 'Non printed characters have {} names.
     
Next
```